# Align content in center css

Tags: html, css

How to align content in the center?

Currently the Header Text
and
the Login/Password Input fields
are not aligned in the center, and align seperately

Example:
"Header1"
"Header2"
...."login"
...."password"
...."buttons"

Header Fields:

```
<body>
    <div class="headerLogo" align="center">
        <img src="images/login.png"><br><br><br>
        <h1 class="form-signin-heading">
            <b>header1header1</b>
        </h1>
        <h3 class="form-signin-heading">
            headerheader2
        </h3>
    </div><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Login Input Fields:

```
    <div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" method="Post">
        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="email"> 
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="pwd"> 
        <label class="checkbox"> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
            Keep Login
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" type="submit">
            <b>로그인</b>
        </button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><b>Email Join</b></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><b>Find Password</b></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body><!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering placeholder text alone isn't browser wide supported. For safari and mozilla (seems to work in chrome) you can use:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align:center;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BGMd7/1/)

If you are OK with the text that the user inputs be centered as well use:

```
input {
    text-align:center;
}
```

EDIT: I'm assuming you are using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

try `<div class="container" style="margin-right:30px">` if that doesn't work putting it onto jsfiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap and by the looks of you code you are, you can center text by adding the class "text-center".

```
<p class="text-center">aligned center</p>
```

And some other useful alignments available in bootstrap :

```
<p class="text-left">aligned left</p>
<p class="text-right">aligned right</p>
<p class="text-justify">justified</p>
```